# flutter custom loader animation

Tags: flutter, animation, loader

this is my code for having a loader that rotates with different 8 dots which 3 of them has a different color (pink, blue, and green) the other 5 are grey i want to animate the loader to show 1 of the three colored dot at time when rotating, i'm really stuck here can you please help me achieve thi kind of animation and thank you
this is my code

```
class CustomLoader extends StatefulWidget {
  const CustomLoader({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _CustomLoaderState createState() => _CustomLoaderState();
}

class _CustomLoaderState extends State<CustomLoader> with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin {
  final double initialRadius = 20.0;
  double radius = 20.0;
  late final AnimationController _animationController = AnimationController(vsync: this, duration: Duration(seconds: 2))..repeat();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return AnimatedBuilder(
      animation: _animationController,
      builder: (BuildContext context, Widget? child) {
        return Transform.rotate(
          angle: _animationController.value * 2 * pi,
          child: Container(
            width: 100.0,
            height: 100.0,
            child: Stack(
              children: [
                const Dot(
                  radius: 30.0,
                  color: Colors.transparent,
                ),
                Transform.translate(
                  offset: Offset(
                    radius * cos(pi / 4),
                    radius * sin(pi / 4),
                  ),
                  child: const Dot(
                    radius: 10.0,
                    color: AppColors.greenColorLight,
                  ),
                ),
                Transform.translate(
                  offset: Offset(
                    radius * cos(2 * pi / 4),
                    radius * sin(2 * pi / 4),
                  ),
                  child: const Dot(
                    radius: 10.0,
                    color: AppColors.secondaryColorLight,
                  ),
                ),
                Transform.translate(
                  offset: Offset(
                    radius * cos(3 * pi / 4),
                    radius * sin(3 * pi / 4),
                  ),
                  child: const Dot(
                    radius: 10.0,
                    color: AppColors.primayColorLight,
                  ),
                ),
                Transform.translate(
                  offset: Offset(
                    radius * cos(4 * pi / 4),
                    radius * sin(4 * pi / 4),
                  ),
                  child: const Dot(
                    radius: 10.0,
                    color: AppColors.borderGreyColor,
                  ),
                ),
                Transform.translate(
                  offset: Offset(
                    radius * cos(5 * pi / 4),
                    radius * sin(5 * pi / 4),
                  ),
                  child: const Dot(
                    radius: 10.0,
                    color: AppColors.borderGreyColor,
                  ),
                ),
                Transform.translate(
                  offset: Offset(
                    radius * cos(6 * pi / 4),
                    radius * sin(6 * pi / 4),
                  ),
                  child: const Dot(
                    radius: 10.0,
                    color: AppColors.borderGreyColor,
                  ),
                ),
                Transform.translate(
                  offset: Offset(
                    radius * cos(7 * pi / 4),
                    radius * sin(7 * pi / 4),
                  ),
                  child: const Dot(
                    radius: 10.0,
                    color: AppColors.borderGreyColor,
                  ),
                ),
                Transform.translate(
                  offset: Offset(
                    radius * cos(8 * pi / 4),
                    radius * sin(8 * pi / 4),
                  ),
                  child: const Dot(
                    radius: 10.0,
                    color: AppColors.borderGreyColor,
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        );
      },
    );
  }
}

class Dot extends StatelessWidget {
  final double? radius;
  final Color color;
  const Dot({Key? key, this.radius, required this.color}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Center(
      child: Container(
        width: this.radius,
        height: this.radius,
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          color: this.color,
          shape: BoxShape.circle,
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

change color of a dot during a interval

```
import 'dart:async';
import 'dart:math';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class CustomLoader extends StatefulWidget {
  const CustomLoader({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _CustomLoaderState createState() => _CustomLoaderState();
}

class _CustomLoaderState extends State<CustomLoader> with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin {
  final double initialRadius = 20.0;
  double radius = 20.0;
  double pi = 3.14;
  late final AnimationController _animationController = AnimationController(vsync: this, duration: Duration(seconds: 2))..repeat();

  List<Color> colors = [Colors.pink,Colors.blue,Colors.green];
    Color colorNow  = Colors.pink;
   int colorIndex = 0;
  void changeColor(){
    if(colorIndex <2){
      colorIndex = colorIndex+1;
      setState(() {
        colorNow = colors[colorIndex];
      });

    }else{
      colorIndex = 0;
      setState(() {
        colorNow = colors[colorIndex];
      });
    }
  }


  Timer? timer;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    timer = Timer.periodic(Duration(seconds: 2), (Timer t) => changeColor());
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    timer?.cancel();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return AnimatedBuilder(
      animation: _animationController,
      builder: (BuildContext context, Widget? child) {
        return Transform.rotate(
          angle: _animationController.value * 2 * pi,
          child: Container(
            width: 100.0,
            height: 100.0,
            child: Stack(
              children: [
                const Dot(
                  radius: 30.0,
                  color: Colors.transparent,
                ),
                Transform.translate(
                  offset: Offset(
                    radius * cos(pi / 4),
                    radius * sin(pi / 4),
                  ),
                  child: const Dot(
                    radius: 10.0,
                    color: Colors.grey,
                  ),
                ),
                Transform.translate(
                  offset: Offset(
                    radius * cos(2 * pi / 4),
                    radius * sin(2 * pi / 4),
                  ),
                  child:  Dot(
                    radius: 10.0,
                    color: Colors.grey,
                  ),
                ),
                Transform.translate(
                  offset: Offset(
                    radius * cos(3 * pi / 4),
                    radius * sin(3 * pi / 4),
                  ),
                  child:  Dot(
                    radius: 10.0,
                    color: colorNow,
                  ),
                ),
                Transform.translate(
                  offset: Offset(
                    radius * cos(4 * pi / 4),
                    radius * sin(4 * pi / 4),
                  ),
                  child:const  Dot(
                    radius: 10.0,
                    color: Colors.grey,
                  ),
                ),
                Transform.translate(
                  offset: Offset(
                    radius * cos(5 * pi / 4),
                    radius * sin(5 * pi / 4),
                  ),
                  child: const Dot(
                    radius: 10.0,
                    color: Colors.grey,
                  ),
                ),
                Transform.translate(
                  offset: Offset(
                    radius * cos(6 * pi / 4),
                    radius * sin(6 * pi / 4),
                  ),
                  child: const Dot(
                    radius: 10.0,
                    color: Colors.grey,
                  ),
                ),
                Transform.translate(
                  offset: Offset(
                    radius * cos(7 * pi / 4),
                    radius * sin(7 * pi / 4),
                  ),
                  child: const Dot(
                    radius: 10.0,
                    color: Colors.grey,
                  ),
                ),
                Transform.translate(
                  offset: Offset(
                    radius * cos(8 * pi / 4),
                    radius * sin(8 * pi / 4),
                  ),
                  child: const Dot(
                    radius: 10.0,
                    color: Colors.grey,
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        );
      },
    );
  }
}

class Dot extends StatelessWidget {
  final double? radius;
  final Color color;
  const Dot({Key? key, this.radius, required this.color}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Center(
      child: Container(
        width: this.radius,
        height: this.radius,
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          color: this.color,
          shape: BoxShape.circle,
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: not exactly what i was looking for but thank you (i don't want the same dot to change it's color i want the next dot to change it's color when arriving on certain dy)

Comment: change Timer Duration value  to AnimationController duration value (2 seconds) and select which position dot you need to change color. then it work like you expected

Comment: how can i specify the position ?

Comment: plaese i'm till stuck ....